# Recommendations for New Ubuntu User?

Tags: sound, software-recommendation

I just installed Ubuntu and I'm wondering if there is anything you recommend I do? This is my first experience with an OS other than Windows so it all seems foreign to me.

Comment: This site is not a forum its for asking and answering specific clear questions.  As such this question is off topic here and will probably be closed as **primarily opinion-based**.  You can ask this on the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/) however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the Ubuntu world, this will be a pretty pleasant journey of discovery but somehow steep learning curve but with time and patience you'll get a grasp on things.

I'd recommend the perfect desktop from [HowtoForge](http://www.howtoforge.com/the-perfect-desktop-ubuntu-13.04-raring-ringtail).

Answer (score 0):

Try updating. Your audio drivers may be out of date. If the driver isn't present, you may have to install it manually.

As for getting started, you'll find ubuntu contains many basic apps and utilities already(such as LibreOFfice, which is kind of like Microsoft Office, if you installed Ubuntu from ubuntu.com".

If you want to be able to use Windows apps on Ubuntu, check out Wine.

In the case you want to have remote access, there is SSH. For multiple users, there is a user management package if you want to do it the grphical way. For antivirus, check out ClamAV(again, clamtk if you want gui)

Enjoy and Welcome to Ubuntu! :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll check em all out. As for the sound issue, how do I update/install the drivers? When I check the sound settings, it doesn't seem to list my output which is HDMI. Could that be the issue?

Comment: @user206102, please integrate supplementary information into your question so that people can understand your situation without needing to go through comments. Also, you should try to ask just one focused question rather than something like "I'm wondering if there is anything you recommend I do?" because that's what this site prefers.

Answer (score 0):

First setup internet connection on ubuntu. After setting up net connection run command "sudo apt-get update" on terminal. After installing drivers you can try using ubuntu software center to install different apps.